# How to secure php file for cron tasks only?

Tags: php, database, automation, cron

I realize there are similar posts to this out there, but rest assured, this isn't a duplicate post!

I have a site on a godaddy server. I DO NOT have access to the outside of the root of my server (everything is public).

I have a file delete.php that needs to run on CRON, and only by CRON. The file should not execute manually at all by anyone for any reason.

Given the above, I am trying to secure my file as much as possible so let'smake this an experiment in security.

So far, I have the following with the goal of making the file as secure as possible:

```
<?php
$isCLI = ( php_sapi_name() == 'cli' );

if (!$isCLI) {
    die("cannot run!");
} else {
    if(!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])){
        // Do the task here
    }else{
        die("cannot run!");
    }
}
?>
```

So, is this logically secure? How can it be made even more secure? godaddy can only allow me to set a date/time to run a file, nothing more.

Comment: Why are your cron scripts even in the document root of the webserver?

Comment: just put it out side the web root.

Comment: Please read guys. I DO NOT have access to the outside of my root. My entire directory is public. Again, godaddy DOES NOT allow access to outside of the root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking for the `cli` SAPI is sufficient; a user executing it via apache (be it mod_php or fastcgi or cgi) will never cause PHP to be called through the CLI sapi. You can get rid of the ugly `else {}` around your real code though; if you `exit;` at the end of the *then* block there is no need for an *else* block.

However, not putting that kind of script in the document root at all would be much cleaner. If that's not possible, also consider using `.htaccess`:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

If the files are in a folder which shouldn't be locked down completely, wrap those lines in `<Files whatever.php>...</Files>`

Comment: I agree that not putting the script in root is cleaner but like I said, that is IMPOSSIBLE with godaddy.

Comment: @Jonathan: That's the very reason why I transferred my site from GD last year :(

Answer (score 1):

Of course, placing those files outside the webroot would be the preferred way of doing it.
On the other hand, you could create `.htaccess` which defines `Deny all` rule for all access. This way `Deny all` prevents direct server access but PHP CLI would still be able to access it.

Comment: can you elaborate on how such a line would look like in my htaccess file?

Comment: If they are in a separate folder: `Order deny,allow` and `deny from all`. If they aren't, wrap those two lines in `<Files cronwhatever.php>...</Files>`

Comment: Would CHMOD the delete.php file to 644 be effective?

Comment: by no means but there should be "one directive per line". I don't think that 644 would do any good cause as far as I recall `.php` files are being **read** by Apache, not executed. Maybe `PHP CGI` works differently...